# Passing dictionary value to hashing function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have a dictionary, the values of which contain filenames and their paths.

I also have a MD5hashing function, which I want to call with relevant values from the dictionary.

```
with open('/tmp/foo') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        files[row['size']].append(row['file'])
        # print the contents of the files defaultdict dictionary
    for key, value in files.items():
        if len([item for item in value if item]) > 1:
            print (key+'\n')
            print(md5Checksum(value))
```

My md5 function is:

```
def md5Checksum(filePath):
    with open(filePath, 'rb') as fh:
        m = hashlib.md5()
        while True:
            data = fh.read(8192)
            if not data:
                break
            m.update(data)
        return m.hexdigest()
```

When i call it as is I am getting

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

If i change the calling command to:

```
print(md5Checksum(**value))
```

I get:

> TypeError: md5Checksum() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list'

Can someone point out the obvious fix which I'm missing please?

Comment: `value` is here a list of filenames, not a filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `value` is, based on the rest of the code, a list of filenames, not a filename. You thus should add an extra loop. It might also be better to do the fitering *before* adding the filename to the list:

```
with open('/tmp/foo') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row['file']:  # preventing adding the file in the first place
            files[row['size']].append(row['file'])


for key, values in files.items():
    for value in values:
        print ('{}\n{}'.format(key, md5Checksum(value)))
```

Answer (score 2):

the `open(filePath, 'rb')`, expect the `filepath` argument to be of type str , while when calling the `md5Checksum(value)`, you are passing it a variable of type list, so may be you should add a loop iterating over the items in value, and pass those items to the `md5Checksum` function